Signals with null-assertion
In a template, lets say we have something like:
@if (someSignal()?.someProperty!.trim().length > 0) {...}

someSignal is not required.
not-null assertion on someProperty causes everything after this statement to block (not only the part within the @if block.
There are ways to circumvent that, I am just curious if this is expected behavior?

Instead of !. try using TypeScript safe access ?. which will perform a sort of null check on each field and will render only when the condition is true.
If there is a possibility of a value being undefined, you should prefer ?. instead of !. since it won't error out if the value is undefined.
Due to some template error, the other content fails to render is my guess.
@if (someSignal()?.someProperty?.trim()?.length > 0) {...}


yeah, i actually ended up preparing the value in @let block and then have that properly null checked. What I was surprised with is that the rest of the template is blocked from rendering. and there is no error in template, its straightforward. So I was wondering if there is it really possible that code just stucks there and waits for a signal to produce a value? I suspect that is actually what's going on because even event listeners (click) do not work in other components. Only once I close this component, click events are actually handled. So, there must be something deeper going on here.

so, code gets to this point, signal doesn't have a value, everything is blocked, you click on some totally different part of the UI, nothing happens. Only when you close this component, your click (the one you already did) gets handled.

@tlzg check the console for errors, check the console tab for any errors firstly, then comment out the if condition to identify if that is the culprit, also check if you have changedetection set to OnPush, if so, then you should use cdr.detectChanges in few places to update the UI

console is clear of errors.  cdr.detectChanges is maybe a good point. could you elaborate a bit please, why would you need to trigger it manually?

@tlzg Only browser events (click, etc), signals, @Input, setTimeout, these only trigger change detection when you set OnPush, if you are using signals incorrectly, that might be causing change detection to not fire, remember, when working with signals that have an array or object, updating the inner values, does not change the memory location of the array or object, so signal does not identify that an update has been made. It all depends on the code you have.

yeah, that is all clear. but imagine that signal doesn't actually ever change. so, lets say the part of the code you mark as not null ( someSignal().someProperty! ) actually never gets a value. I understand its a wrong usage here but I would still expect other parts of the application (in totally different components) to render and react to click events. Can't understand why would this not null assertion block event handlers in other components.

@tlzg I can't diagnose without looking at the code, best a working example where the issue happens. might be some CSS blocking the click events, maybe remove OnPush Change detection, for problems like this, I would comment out part of the code until it starts working, by doing like this you can find the culprit, First comment large chunks, narrow down the problem, by reducing the size of comments within the larger commented block, you can narrow down the problem, like how a binary search works.

yeah, sure. ok, lets wrap up with - you think this not null assertion should not block the rest of the app? (point being, the moment I remove the !, everything works as expected)

@tlzg yes, exactly! use ?. which the parent property is undefined, only when you are sure the value will not be undefined then use !.
